# すでに作られているDockerイメージのレイヤー数を少なく圧縮する方法はありますか？

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
$ docker compose build 
$ docker compose up -d
Error response from daemon: max depth exceeded
```

上記コマンド手順でDockerコンテナを起動しようとしましたが、エラーが発生し、起動できませんでした。
原因としては、Dockerイメージがレイヤー数の上限である125を超過したことが考えられます。

解決する方法として、 --squashオプションを使う方法がありますが、この方法は、DockerのFROMイメージのレイヤー圧縮できないため、要件を満たしませんでした。したがって、別の方法で、この問題に対処しようかと考えています。手段として、 Dockerコンテナ化した後に、export/importすることでレイヤーを束ねるという方法も考えられますが、 定義されているENVなどが消えてしまうという問題があります。Dockerfileを入手して、レイヤーを小さくするという方法もありますが、それは欠点があります。同ファイルに定義されているコマンドに再現性がなかったり、再ビルドに数時間以上かかるケースがあり、非効率な点です。

これらの問題に対処する親Dockerイメージのレイヤー数を小さくする良い解決方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事 [Reduce docker image size by minimizing the number of layers](https://gist.github.com/shinsenter/4f1f4f16a1f5b9a02ef9ba4faf19233d) が参考になるかも。

Comment: ありがとうございます。docker historyでビルド履歴からENVなどを辿るという方法が参考になりました。